# How can I backup Outlook for Mac 2016 on my mac?

Tags: mail.app, backup, email, ms-office, software

I am in need to clean up my outlook for mac 2016 and looking forward to an organized mailbox. But before that, I need to backup all my email database from outlook mac so that I don't lose any emails. The Outlook for mac export is taking a lot of time to export the mailboxes as they are quite large in number. Is there any other way around to backup the outlook for mac 2016?

Comment: I assume you have Time Machine backups of your data, right? If all you want is to have a backup in case something goes wrong while reorganising your mailbox, then it should already be backed up via Time Machine (unless you've specifically excluded it from your TM backups).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What exact Mac model do you have?
2. What exact Mac OS are you running?
3. For Outlook, do you have Office 2008, Office 2011, or Office 2016? I have used all 3, but am most familiar with Email cleaning for Outlook 2011 and (currently) Outlook 2016.
4. Have you ever done any disk cleanup/maintenance/repairs, from a software perspective?
5. Are you making backups to an external device? And if so, what software are you using for that?

Now, regarding Outlook, I assume you have deleted Emails in the past. Also, you should consider deleting any you do not need. For Outlook 2011, there is a way to rebuild its database (ie, Identity "file") to permanently remove deleted Emails. (For Outlook 2016, the procedure is different).

Here's a link for outook for mac 2016 database rebuild:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1274738-office-2016-for-mac-manual-database-identity-rebuild

If that also does not work then you can opt for third party apps, one which is making headlines now a days is mail backup x, check out one of the articles:http://www.mailbackupx.com/how-to-scenerios/how-to-backup-outlook-mac-mails-on-mac.html

Please note that all the third party apps are paid. First go for the manual procedure.

I hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let the export complete. The internal storage of mails in Outlook 2016 for Mac is a cached version for all imap / google accounts that changes internally from version to version.

The export yields a far more standard and stable data dump which serves the purpose of being importable at a later date.

If you have local folders - on my Mac then things are slightly more complicated. Perhaps that's part of the slower export?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some similar threads that might help:-

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8acc49d-535d-4ee3-98b0-3cd58ba106f0/looking-for-outlook-for-mac-export-alternative?forum=Office2016forMac
- https://discussions.apple.com/message/31602765#31602765